# Proccess.Start in MVC4 project not working when published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, powershell

From My MVC4 page I need to call a Powershell script. I don't really need to return any result from it, just make sure the script runs.

When I Debug in my computer, it works fine, but when I try after publishing, it just doesn't do anything or show any error.

This is the code in my Controller:

```
using (new Impersonator(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonatorUser"], 
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonatorDomain"], 
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonatorPassword"]))
{
    var scr = new PSScriptParam("\\\\SERVER\\...\\Script.ps1", Param);
    scr.Run();
}
```

The class PSScriptParam is just this:

```
public class PSScriptParam
{
    public string Script { get; set; }
    public string Param { get; set; }

    public PSScriptParam(string Path, string param)
    {
        Param = param;
        Script = Path;
    }

    public void Run()
    {

        try
        {
            Process _Proc = Process.Start("Powershell.exe", Script + " '" + Param + "'");

        }

        catch (Exception err)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("\\\\SERVER\\...\\Error.txt", err.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

The impersonator is using a domain admin account, and the execution policy is set as unrestricted in the server (there is no problem running the script from the cmd).

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the Error message?

Comment: There is no error message, the script just doesn't run, the other processes in that action work fine (it also saves some data to a database). If anyone has a better idea to catch the exception, I'd do it...

Comment: SO it doesnt log anything to your Error.txt file? Have you tried removing the try catch and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I tried first without the try/catch, I added it to check if I could see the exception... I also tried using the impersonator within the class PSScriptParam, but the same happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved after applying pending updates in the server... Even if I'm not sure why it didn't work, updating Windows solved the problem.